# Why PHP treating "1" as integer in array_merge()

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

Why PHP treating "1" as integer in `array_merge()`

**ex.**

```
$arr1 = array( "1"=>1, 2 , 3 );
$arr2 = array( "1"=>1, 2 );
print_r(array_merge( $arr1 , $arr2 ));
var_dump("1");
var_dump(1);
```

**Outputs:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 2
)

string(1) "1" int(1)
```

As per `array_merge()` function :-
If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.

Answer (score 4):

This is not array_merge() related, but rather on how array keys are handled by PHP. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php for implicit cast of keys.

Answer (score 0):

You simply shouldn't use numeric values as string keys because they are treated as numerical keys.

The most important thing in this case is:

> Strings containing valid integers will be cast to the integer type.
>   E.g. the key "8" will actually be stored under 8. On the other hand
>   "08" will not be cast, as it isn't a valid decimal integer.

This above is related to PHP arrays as in [PHP Arrays manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

You can see it using this sample code:

```
$arr1 = array( "1"=>1, "01" => 4,  2 , 3 );

var_dump($arr1);
```

It will return:

> array(4) { [1](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)=> int(1) ["01"]=> int(4) [2]=> int(2) [3]=> int(3) }

So your key `"1"` became numerical key but key `"01"` is still string key